# How to set data usage cycle to non-monthly value?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-monitoring

My network operator charges to my account every 28 days rather than every month. How can I change the data usage cycle length under `Settings > Connections > Data Usage` accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no option to do so in the stock data usage controls. You will be better off installing a third party app, such as onavo count.

Comment: Thanks, but where do we find this **onavo count**? How about a hyperlink to help a reader not to go looking at shady websites inadvertently?

Comment: That's available in the Google Play store, hence I thought it wouldn't require a link. Nevertheless, the link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Donavo+count&pcampaignid=APPU_1_4-pCVYzCFae4mwXHnQE

Answer (score 1):

This feature is in Android roadmap. You can just wait or vote for it
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23676